# HTTP 404 when importing data from Google Drive

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was trying to import a record from `Google Drive` to the colaboratory notebook I'm using, and I've got an HTTP 404 error. In the `JSON` containing the exception captured it says that I'm accessing drive without authentication (which is not the case):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I've tried to refresh the notebook to require a new authentication, but wasn't able to do so.

Comment: Can you share a sample notebook that leads to this error?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it. It suddenly started working again.

Comment: I am also getting the same error.